# How to select a block in visual mode and delete this block and immediately enter insert mode?

Tags: visual-mode, replace

for one single word, the job is quite easy: we just do a 'cw'

what if I select a certain text and I want to replace this block with one word?

obviously I can do a 'x' and then 'i', is there a one key-stoke solution?

in other words, after I select the block in visual mode, what is the fastest way to do 'delete' and then enter insert mode?

any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can do exactly this with <kbd>c</kbd>. From `:help v_c`:

```
{Visual}["x]c   or                  *v_c* *v_s*
{Visual}["x]s       Delete the highlighted text [into register x] and
            start insert (for {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not
            in Vi}
```

In general, most commands that work in normal mode will work the same way in visual mode. So since you can do `cw`, you can do `c` in visual mode and it will have the same effect. Same for `d`, `y`, `gu`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the selection using visual mode and then hit <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd> to remove the selected text and directly enter insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can enter visual mode V-Line `Shift + v` then select your code with `j`(down) or `k` (up). Then `Shift + s` will empty your block of code and enter insert mode.

Explanation:

- `Shift + v` let you select entire lines.
- `Shift + s` replace your selection and enters insert mode.

Now, an even better tip... if your code is between `{` and `}` and your cursor is placed inside those, then you can just type `ci{` and it will leave everything inside `{` and `}` blank *and* enter insert mode.

Explanation:

- `c` change
- `i` internal
- `{` delimiter, it can be `(` or `{` or `"`

Here are both:

[image]

I hope this will help you.
Cheers!